# php file not connecting to azure database(mySQL-in-app of app service)

Tags: php, database-connection, azure-sql-database

I am using 'mysql-in-app' of App Service in azure.I want to add,delete,edit and view data using maintenance page. I have written php code for that. I am not able to connect to the mysql db.

I have tried this locally for local db using ->

`$conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','samdb');`

its working fine.

But I am trying to connect to azure db using this->

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:50721','azure','6#vWHD_$','localdb');
```

here its not working.,

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the connection information needed to connect to the Azure Database for MySQL. You need the fully qualified server name and login credentials.

[image]

Use the following code to connect and create a table by using CREATE TABLE SQL statement.

The code uses the MySQL Improved extension (mysqli) class included in PHP. The code calls methods mysqli_init and mysqli_real_connect to connect to MySQL. Then it calls method mysqli_query to run the query. Then it calls method mysqli_close to close the connection.

Replace the host, username, password, and db_name parameters with your own values.

```
<?php
$host = 'mydemoserver.mysql.database.azure.com';
$username = 'myadmin@mydemoserver';
$password = 'your_password';
$db_name = 'your_database';

//Establishes the connection
$conn = mysqli_init();
mysqli_real_connect($conn, $host, $username, $password, $db_name, 3306);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
die('Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Run the create table query
if (mysqli_query($conn, '
CREATE TABLE Products (
`Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`ProductName` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
`Color` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
`Price` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);
')) {
printf("Table created\n");
}

//Close the connection
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code using MySQL in-app Get the database connection string and connect to the database:

```
$connectstr_dbhost = '';
$connectstr_dbname = '';
$connectstr_dbusername = '';
$connectstr_dbpassword = '';

foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, "MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb") !== 0) {
        continue;
    }

    $connectstr_dbhost = preg_replace("/^.*Data Source=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
    $connectstr_dbname = preg_replace("/^.*Database=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
    $connectstr_dbusername = preg_replace("/^.*User Id=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
    $connectstr_dbpassword = preg_replace("/^.*Password=(.+?)$/", "\\1", $value);
}

$link = mysqli_connect($connectstr_dbhost, $connectstr_dbusername, $connectstr_dbpassword,$connectstr_dbname);
```

For more details ,you can see this tutorial: [Announcing MySQL in-app for Web Apps (Windows)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/08/18/announcing-mysql-in-app-preview-for-web-apps/)

You also can get these connection string on Azure protal:
[image]

Please see: [Azure Database for MySQL: Use PHP to connect and query data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-php#get-connection-information).

So you code could be this and you can try again:

```
$connectstr_dbhost = 'mydemoserver.mysql.database.azure.com';
$connectstr_dbname = 'myadmin@mydemoserver';
$connectstr_dbusername = 'your_password';
$connectstr_dbpassword = 'your_database';

$conn = mysqli_connect($connectstr_dbhost, $connectstr_dbusername, $connectstr_dbpassword,$connectstr_dbname);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is different from what I have asked. I added phpMyAdmin to App service by using extension in app service. I have not used separate service for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the port seperately like so:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','azure','6#vWHD_$','localdb', '50721');
```